# CountDown using NSTimer in swift

Tags: swift, nstimer, countdown

I'm still learning swift, and i'm trying to design an application and in one section i had this game timer that is set to 7 minutes ( gonna add figure out how to let the client change that later), for now it's 7:00, i have added 2 buttons, 
Start, Pause. and i wanted to let Start, starts the countDown until 00:00, then i was planning to add a pop up message saying time is up!.

Code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var countDown: UILabel!

var counter = 60
var timer = NSTimer()

func update() {

    if counter > 0 {
        countDown.text = String(counter--)
    }

}

@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@IBAction func pause(sender: UIButton) {
     // timer.invalidate() stops the whole thing...
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

however, the app keeps on crashing... and i don't know how to make the timer more than 60 seconds, like how to represent it.

Comment: Could you include what error the app crashes with?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[IwannaPlay.ViewController Start:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd039c25820'

Comment: Go and check your start button on interface builder.  Seem like it is tied up to wrong viewcontroller and method ->(IwannaPlay.ViewController Start:])

Comment: @bpolat turned out that my button is linked to 3 things, u just solved most of my problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would not be the way that I would do a countdown timer.

```
@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {
     self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    startTime = NSDate() // new instance variable that you would need to add.
}

func update() {
    let elapsedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)
    let currTime = totalTime - elapsedTime 
    //total time is an instance variable that is the total amount of time in seconds that you want
    countDown.text = String(currTime)
    if currTime < 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        //do other stuff that you need to do when time runs out.
    }
}
```

Also make sure that your IBAction outlets are right in interface builder.

Comment: ok so added this to my global variables, 
     var totalTime = 60
     var timer = NSTimer()
     var startTime = NSDate()

and in the Start function i added : startTime = NSDate()

This is my update function: 
        let elapsedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)
        let currTime = totalTime - Int(elapsedTime)
        countDown.text = String(currTime)
        if currTime < 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }

Comment: however app is still crashing, this is the message i get:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[IwannaPlay.ViewController Start:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd039c25820'

Comment: @AymanAbuassonon okay, that means that there was something wrong with the selector you used. Check my updated code on the start function and especially the `#selector(ViewController.update(_:))` line. But the error also might be in you interface builder file. Try to make sure that the IBAction is right.

Comment: after fixing the crashing thingy now it works perfectly, this is all new to me, thanks.